# When trying to setup secure proxy connection Chrome responds with ERR_PROXY_CERTIFICATE_INVALID

Tags: windows, ssl-certificate, squid, google-chrome

Chrome is on Windows 7, proxy - Squid on Ubuntu. I am using self signed certificate, its CA have been already added to trusted so certificate is shown as trusted by Windows, too. Cname in certificate is set to proxy IP adress. But Chrome keeps rejecting it. Where should i add it and what certificate should I add? CA or proxy?
I have found similar [question](https://superuser.com/questions/489042/using-secure-proxies-with-google-chrome), but it is not my case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install into Trusted Root Certification Authorities, see https://docs.diladele.com/administrator_guide_stable/https_filtering/install_certificates/win_ie_chrome.html

You did follow https://docs.diladele.com/faq/squid/sslbump_squid_windows.html?

Comment: It is installed Trusted Root Certification Authorities. No, I am not trying to do SSL Bump, I am trying to make connection between proxy and client secure.